# Where is the WebAssembly stack-based virtual machine implemented?

Tags: virtual-machine, webassembly

Quoting https://webassembly.org/ :

> WebAssembly (abbreviated Wasm) is a binary instruction format for a stack-based virtual machine. Wasm is designed as a portable compilation target for programming languages, enabling deployment on the web for client and server applications.

I have read about stack-based virtual machines on Wikipedia. Still, I wonder where the WebAssembly stack-based virtual machine resides. Is it embedded in the javascript engine (for example, on V8)? Does V8 hand the .wasm file to another virtual machine to run it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This statement describes the concept that Wasm instructions operate on a value stack. For example, `i32.add` takes two i32 values from this stack, and pushes another (the result) onto that stack. Note that this is an abstract, theoretical model.

Wasm engines, of course, have to accept these instructions, and behave as if there was this stack that the instructions use to exchange input and output values. They may or may not map this conceptual behavior to an actual stack, that's an implementation detail. In fact, it's common for engines to do both: non-optimizing baseline compilers often, but not always, map the conceptual stack onto an actual stack in memory (because that makes the compiler simpler and hence faster), whereas optimizing last-tier compilers typically use an IR ("intermediate representation") in SSA ("static single assignment") form, which is not a conceptual stack machine (and makes the compiler more powerful).

The alternative to a "stack machine" is a "register machine". For example, both x86 and ARM machine code is based on this model: instructions encode which registers they use to take input values and return results. It's also possible to build engines based on a "register machine" model; V8's "Ignition" interpreter (used for JavaScript) is an example of that. It would have been possible to design the Wasm instruction format as a register-based thing -- I'm not sure why it wasn't done that way; probably because modules in binary form would have been bigger if e.g. `i32.add` had to specify that it takes its two inputs from virtual register x and virtual register y, instead of just implicitly taking the topmost two stack values).

Comment: thank you. the term 'virtual machine' implies isolation. so does stack-based virtual machine provide isolation?

Comment: No, "virtual machine" does not imply isolation. It implies _virtualization_, for example: taking a physical register-based x86 machine and building a software layer on top of it that pretends to be a stack-based machine that can execute Wasm modules. (It's true that various kinds of virtual machines (V8, JVM, Qemu, VMware, ...) are often also used for (and built to provide) isolation purposes, but that's orthogonal: you can have isolation without using virtual machines (that'd be a "sandbox"), and you can have virtual machines that provide no meaningful isolation.)